# Windows Phone client for site

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to write a client for a site on windows phone 7 but the site has no API. The client should simply take data from a website and display of a suitable form. What can I use to write such a client

Comment: You need to provide more information - this question is too vague.

Comment: a) Sites arent 'on' wp7, b) a client is nothing, c) which site doesnt have an API, d) what data should be taken from the unknown site? e) define suitable form? f) You can use a keyboard to write most programs.

Comment: Is it your own site or a 3rd party one? This question is way too vague for an accurate answer. I suggest you improve it with examples and more specific information.

Answer (score 1):

Generically what I believe you're looking for is called a screen scraper.  Once you've scraped out the data you can then design an interface to display what you're looking for.

Comment: Did you mean to use a parser, but it does not slow down the application

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to search for RSS on that site. RSS is an open XML protocol and it would be easy for you to display site updates :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a lot of assumptions here because you didn't provide a specific question. Please edit it to clarify what *exactly* you are trying to accomplish, if possible with some code samples of what you tried.

If I understood correctly, the only thing you can do is extract the "information" you were talking about from the HTML of the site. You can use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for that purpose. More specifically, you'd want to use the [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync(Uri)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to download the HTML of the web page. 
Once you've done that, the next step is to either parse it into an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or find the information you are looking for with a [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).